# Can I use pipedoutputstream for multi threads?

Tags: java

Can i use one pipedoutputstream for multi threads and connect it to one pipedinputstream, then get all the output from the multi threads?

Following is the code snippet, what i want is the modify and delete thread's output can be used for sync thread, but delete thread's output is missed.
List P4Thread's run() method in the end.

```
PipedInputStream input = new PipedInputStream();
PipedOutputStream output = new PipedOutputStream();

input.connect(output);

P4Thread syncthread = new P4Thread (new String[]{p4exe, "-x-", "sync", "-f"},input, out);
P4Thread modifythread = new P4Thread (new String[]{p4exe, "diff", "-se"},new ClosedInputStream(), output);
P4Thread deletethread = new P4Thread (new String[]{p4exe, "diff", "-sd"},new ClosedInputStream(), output);  

try {
    syncthread.start();
    modifythread.run();
    output.flush();

    deletethread.run();
    output.flush();
    output.close();

    syncthread .join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        syncthread .interrupt();
    }

public void run() { 
Launcher.ProcStarter ps = new Launcher.LocalLauncher(listener).launch(); 
ps.envs(env).stdin(input).stdout(output).cmds(cmdList); 
if (workDir != null) { 
    ps.pwd(workDir); 
}
try{
   ps.join();
   }catch (InterruptedException e) {
            if (output != null && closePipes) {
                IOUtils.closeQuietly(output);
            }
            //return -1;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if (output != null && closePipes) {
                IOUtils.closeQuietly(output);
            }
        } finally {
            if (closePipes) {
                IOUtils.closeQuietly(input);
                IOUtils.closeQuietly(output);
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, as long as you take care of synchronizing your multi-threaded writes so they don't interleave.

Comment: Thanks! I think it should be ok as well. But i don't know why it always lose some output from a thread.

Comment: @hotnwwp The only way you can 'lose output' via a piped stream is by failing to flush or close it.

Comment: I update the question with code snippet. I do the flush and close operation. It seems deletethread's output is missed

Comment: @hotnwwp Now I *really* don't understand. Why start() a thread and join() it straight away? You may as well just call its run() method.

Comment: syncthread waits for modifythread and deletethread's stdout as it stdin, start() will call the run() method and join() wait for the thread's termination.

Comment: @hotnwwp You have `modifythread.start();` followed immediately by `modifythread.join();`. This is entirely equivalent to `modifythread.run()` except that it wastes a thread. Same for `deletethread`.start()/join().

Comment: ...... I do get the result from modifythread, so I don't think it wastes a thread. I write it like that because I want deletethread's running after modifythread's over.

Comment: @hotnwwp I didn't say you wouldn't. Of course you get the result. It runs. You would also get it just by calling run(). Try it. You would get sequential execution by calling `modifythread.run()` then `deletethread.run()`. You are making this a lot more complex than it really is.

Comment: OK.You are right.It is a bit complex.Thanks! I update the code, but I still can't get the deletethread's output.

Comment: @hotnwwp Perhaps it is now time to confide in us what your `P4Thread` does.

Comment: Yep. I launch a process and waits for its completion like following, Launcher.ProcStarter is Hudson's package. public void run() { Launcher.ProcStarter ps = new Launcher.LocalLauncher(listener).launch(); ps.envs(env).stdin(input).stdout(output).cmds(cmdList); if (workDir != null) { ps.pwd(workDir); } ps.join(); }

Comment: @hotnwwp Don't post code in comments, it's futile, because illegible. Edit it into your post.

Comment: OK.Thanks. I add it in the post.

Comment: @hotnwwp You still have interrupts for threads which have now never started. What is syncthread?

Comment: Yep.There are interrupts. I didn't paste it here. About syncthread, it executes perforce command "p4 -x- sync -f". The input coming from the other threads' output.

Comment: @hotnwwp You are missing the point. You can't interrupt threads that haven't started. It will fail. Remove the code concerned: `modifythread.interrupt()` and `deletethread.interrupt()`. You still haven't posted the code of P4Thread but clearly it isn't doing the I/O properly between the Process and the pipe.

Comment: OK.I removed modifythread.interrupt() and deletethread.interrupt(). I have already posted P4thread's code, Method run(). I put all the code together.

Comment: @hotnwwp Now you are assuming we all know what `Launcher.ProcStarter` does. We don't. Is it really worthwhile keeping it a secret for ten days?

Comment: :) No.It is not a secret.Launcher.ProcStarter is Hudson's model, it is open source.I didn't paste it here because the codes are really massive. Sorry for not making it clear.I copy the code link here:[link](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/Launcher.java)